# XP support for SQL Express 2008 R2

Tags: windows-xp, sql-server-express

I noticed that the SQL Express 2008 R2 does not list Windows XP as a supported operating system.  While it seems to work fine, I'd need to be sure that everything is going to work on an XP machine should I deploy R2.

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=e08766ce-fc9d-448f-9e98-fe84ad61f135

Otherwise I need to deploy SQL Express 2008 SP1.

Anybody have positive or negative experiences with R2 on XP?

Comment: I just installed it on my XP system last night and it worked fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the `detailed Systems Requirements` and it will bring you here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(SQL.105).aspx#Express32

Windows XP SP3 Home

Windows XP SP3 Professional

Windows XP SP3 Tablet

Windows XP SP3 Media Center 2002

Windows XP SP3 Media Center 2004

Windows XP SP3 Media Center 2005

Windows XP Professional SP3 Reduced Media

Windows XP Home Edition SP3 Reduced Media

Answer (score 0):

I have been using SQL 2008 R2 (express and standard editions) across Windows XP (service packed as specified), Vista, 8, 2003 Sever, 2008 server. It has been absolutely solid in all respects.